# Does MVC Code first eliminate the need to use DB projects to source control the DB and be in sync?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, ef-code-first, synchronization

We are planning a rewrite and I want to get the latest tools to make sure we are doing things the best way. I like how code first keeps the DB structure in code.. which is already source controlled.. So I am hoping that would remove the need for a DB project..  Yes? No ?

DB projects also allow you to sync data between enviorments but  that is something else that has nothing to do with code first

Comment: On a related note. If there are any samples besides nerd dinner and MVC music store that would demonstrate best practices let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Entity Framework Code First you *can* write things out in C# code and have it create/persist the data. Since you can source control C# code, you can source control the database, but only the schema. You won't be able to 'source control' the data.

Personally, I don't use it because it forces you to do some wonky stuff such as declaring properties as `virtual` and using decorators all over the place. Not only that but you really on the framework to do a lot of things behind the scenes and when things go wrong that's never good.

The route I choose and that works very well for me is to declare a Project.Domain class library project with the Entity Framework generated model from an existing database.

Then I would reference this project from my Project.WebUI (my MVC3 project) and have access only to public repository classes.

So my project looks like:

[image]

Comment: Allthe examples lately seem to be using code first.. But I am scared of the magic.. and it IS easier to just create a data structure and slap a EF diagram on top of it.. There part of me that wants to be cutting edge. What does your dbCreationScript do ?

Comment: @punkouter: All it is is TSQL `create table` commands, nothing extravagant.